# How to proceed request in IIS if there is a time limitation for one request

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an asp core web service which can get about 2 millions requests per day. I run this web service on Azure. It's a just xml request-response. Sometimes in a business time we have a big loading. However I need to be sure that I send response in 5 seconds.

I make logic which is send blank response if calculation is not finished by Middleware (Handler). And everything looks ok. However there is a problem that I can not check request timelife coz there is a Queue in Application Pool and all requests can live for some time in Queue.How can I be sure that I handle request not more then 5 seconds even if my request sleep in a Queue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should architect the application so that the queue is always empty. Make sure that the app can at least start processing on requests immediately. At the beginning of each request you can start the timeout logic and kill the request once the timeout hits.

Doing this takes the IIS/ASP.NET queue(s) out of play.

It should not be a performance problem to run the timeout logic since that requires very light processing only.

Probably, you need to use asynchronous IO and asynchronous waiting so that you don't block too many threads.

Your code could look like this:

```
var middlewareTask = ...;
var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(5 seconds);
if (await Task.WhenAny(middlewareTask, timeoutTask) == timeoutTask) {
 CancelRequest();
 SendEmptyResponse();
}
```

If you want to limit the number of concurrent middleware invocations you can use a `SemaphoreSlim` to do that. It supports asynchronous waiting as well.

Comment: Is it possible to return emtpy response directly from iis not asp?

Comment: No, no such support is built-in. And the point of my answer is that it's not necessary. Does this answer help you?